Connect MacOS Sonoma 14.5 to an IKEv2 VPN hosted by Windows Server 2012R2 - NEIKEv2ProtocolErrorDomain Code=12345 "12345"
Tl;DR the error on my mac is EAP only authentication, received notify error Error Domain=NEIKEv2ProtocolErrorDomain Code=12345 "12345" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=12345}
I need to connect from macOS 14.5 to a legacy VPN hosted by a Windows Server 2012R2 RRAS server.
The VPN works perfectly if I connect from Windows 11
The VPN has the default Windows 2012R2 parameters, and you authenticate only with username and password, no certificate and no shared secret. A very simple IKEv2
The encryption parameters are these, read from Windows where it works perfectly:
CipherAlgorithm                     : DES3
HashAlgorithm                       : SHA1
GroupId                             : DH2
KeyModule                           : IkeV2

I set up the VPN on macOS like this:

From the log I see that my mac negotiates the protocols correctly and the server accepts them
2024-07-15 19:04:45.449169+0200 0x54a29    Info        0x0                  12943  0    NEIKEv2Provider: (NetworkExtension) [com.apple.networkextension:Large] IKEv2Session[1, DB7CFC1C5F326B82-0000000000000000] Sending 1 datagrams for packet (message 0): 
    Exchange = IKE_SA_INIT
    Initiator SPI = DB7CFC1C5F326B82
    Initiator = YES
    Response = NO
    Message ID = 0
    Payloads = (
        {
            Payload Type = SA(IKE)
            Proposals = (
                {
                    Number = 1
                    Encryption = (
                        3DES,
                    )
                    Integrity = (
                        HMACSHA196,
                    )
                    PRF = (
                        HMACSHA1,
                    )
                    DH = (
                        MODP1024,
                    )
                    EAP = (
                        MSCHAPv2,
                    )
                    Lifetime = 28800
                },
            )
        },
        {
            Payload Type = KE
            DH = MODP1024
            Public Key = {length = 128, bytes = 0xad59181e b557396c af478f61 83c82bc6 ... 86307964 6b38cb7d }
        },
        {
            Payload Type = NONCE
            Nonce = {length = 16, bytes = 0xb513098cf6bcf36f49b29e45c1088afa}
        },
        {
            Payload Type = Notify
            Notify Type = RedirectSupported
        },
        {
            Payload Type = Notify
            Notify Type = NATDetectionSourceIP
            Notify Data = {length = 20, bytes = 0x6417fa518c80af47b9f3ca979499280f065ad158}
        },
        {
            Payload Type = Notify
            Notify Type = NATDetectionDestinationIP
            Notify Data = {length = 20, bytes = 0x61d3caad6e80e96bd79be2b69519928cf9a8c717}
        },
        {
            Payload Type = Notify
            Notify Type = IKEv2FragmentationSupported
        },
    )

But at some point I get a packet from the server, of type IKE_AUTH where I have a Notify Type = 12345 which sends the whole thing into crisis and in error the connection
2024-07-15 19:04:45.478465+0200 0x54a2a    Default     0x0                  12943  0    NEIKEv2Provider: (NetworkExtension) [com.apple.networkextension:] Connection ready for <NEIKEv2Transport> UDP NAT-T 10.0.0.84:4500 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.207:4500
2024-07-15 19:04:45.478508+0200 0x54a2a    Debug       0x0                  12943  0    NEIKEv2Provider: (NetworkExtension) [com.apple.networkextension:] IKEv2Session[1, DB7CFC1C5F326B82-18571C6A9EADFA57] Sending request of length 356 with ID 1 on <NEIKEv2Transport> UDP NAT-T 10.0.0.84:4500 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.207:4500
2024-07-15 19:04:45.478560+0200 0x54a29    Debug       0x0                  12943  0    NEIKEv2Provider: (NetworkExtension) [com.apple.networkextension:] UDP-NAT-T: Writing frame length 356 for SPI 0000
2024-07-15 19:04:45.506189+0200 0x54a29    Debug       0x0                  12943  0    NEIKEv2Provider: (NetworkExtension) [com.apple.networkextension:] UDP-NAT-T: Reading frame length 68 for SPI 0000
2024-07-15 19:04:45.506547+0200 0x54a29    Info        0x0                  12943  0    NEIKEv2Provider: (NetworkExtension) [com.apple.networkextension:Large] IKEv2Session[1, DB7CFC1C5F326B82-18571C6A9EADFA57] Receiving IKE_AUTH Reply, length 68, ID 1 (DB7CFC1C5F326B82->18571C6A9EADFA57)
2024-07-15 19:04:45.506839+0200 0x54a29    Info        0x0                  12943  0    NEIKEv2Provider: (NetworkExtension) [com.apple.networkextension:Large] IKEv2Session[1, DB7CFC1C5F326B82-18571C6A9EADFA57] Received response: 
    Exchange = IKE_AUTH
    Initiator SPI = DB7CFC1C5F326B82
    Responder SPI = 18571C6A9EADFA57
    Initiator = NO
    Response = YES
    Message ID = 1
    Payloads = (
        {
            Payload Type = Notify
            Notify Type = 12345
            Notify Data = {length = 4, bytes = 0x000035fb}
        },
    )
2024-07-15 19:04:45.507240+0200 0x54a29    Info        0x0                  12943  0    NEIKEv2Provider: (NetworkExtension) [com.apple.networkextension:] IKEv2Session[1, DB7CFC1C5F326B82-18571C6A9EADFA57] Processing response for message 1
2024-07-15 19:04:45.507278+0200 0x54a29    Info        0x0                  12943  0    NEIKEv2Provider: (NetworkExtension) [com.apple.networkextension:] IKEv2Session[1, DB7CFC1C5F326B82-18571C6A9EADFA57], current rtt 29
2024-07-15 19:04:45.507371+0200 0x54a29    Error       0x0                  12943  0    NEIKEv2Provider: (NetworkExtension) [com.apple.networkextension:] [IKE_AUTH R resp1 DB7CFC1C5F326B82-18571C6A9EADFA57] EAP only authentication, received notify error Error Domain=NEIKEv2ProtocolErrorDomain Code=12345 "12345" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=12345}
2024-07-15 19:04:45.507423+0200 0x54a29    Default     0x0                  12943  0    NEIKEv2Provider: (NetworkExtension) [com.apple.networkextension:] IKEv2IKESA[1.1, DB7CFC1C5F326B82-18571C6A9EADFA57] state Connecting -> Disconnected error (null) -> Error Domain=NEIKEv2ProtocolErrorDomain Code=12345 "12345" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=12345}
2024-07-15 19:04:45.509026+0200 0x54a29    Info        0x0                  12943  0    NEIKEv2Provider: (NetworkExtension) [com.apple.networkextension:] IKEv2Session[1, DB7CFC1C5F326B82-18571C6A9EADFA57] Reporting state Disconnected error Error Domain=NEIKEv2ProtocolErrorDomain Code=12345 "12345" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=12345}
2024-07-15 19:04:45.509088+0200 0x54a29    Default     0x0                  12943  0    NEIKEv2Provider: (NetworkExtension) [com.apple.networkextension:] ChildSA[1, (null)-(null)] state Connecting -> Disconnected error (null) -> Error Domain=NEIKEv2ProtocolErrorDomain Code=12345 "12345" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=12345}

What error is this? I'm going crazy
EAP only authentication, received notify error Error Domain=NEIKEv2ProtocolErrorDomain Code=12345 "12345" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=12345}

